# Shortest Path between nodes of some specific type and destination node

Tags: graph, neo4j, path, cypher, shortest-path

Say I want to find the shortest path between some node of a specific type (say "central production unit") and a defined end node (say "consumer" with an id), how to I calculate this in Neo4j with Cypher?

With such queries i'd like to answer questions like: "Which production unit feeds this customer with the shortest distance".

I tried with queries like:

```
match p=AllShortestPaths((source:Asset)-[:LINKS_TO*]-(destination:Asset))
where source.type = 'central production unit' and destination.id = '1234'
return  extract(n in nodes(p)| n.type) as type_path,
        extract(n in nodes(p)| n.id) as id_path,
        length(p) as path_length;
```

queries like the one above will run into an out of memory error.

Using the same query but instead of a **type** of node, entering a specific **id** works perfectly fine.

Sniffing around on Stackoverflow i've found ceveral examples of 1 specific node to 1 other specific node, but not 1 yet to determine node of a certain type to 1 specific node.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found a solution using the sanningTree procedure.

This works pretty fast! I do not understand why. **And** how to include link properties to minimize on fysical properties instead of number of hops.

```
// first match to and collect end nodes
MATCH (m:Asset {type:'central production unit'})
WITH collect(m) as endNodes
MATCH (n:Asset {id:'1234'})
// proc call will be executed per n node, finding the first shortest path found from n to one of the end nodes
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(n, {endNodes:endNodes, limit:1}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```